# Spring: Singleton bean to lazy load in ApplicationContext

Tags: spring

How can I  make a Singleton bean to lazy load in ApplicationContext which loads all Singleton beans eagerly during startup, in Spring base application

Answer (score 2):

In xml config, set **lazy-init** to **true**:

```
<bean id="bar" class="foo.Bar" lazy-init="true">
...
</bean>
```

and in Java config use `@Lazy` annotation for `@Bean`s